# Why does a function write() called from an onclick attribute resolve to document.write()?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, document.write

Why is it that a `write()` function called through an onclick attribute resolves to `document.write()` and replaces the document? Is there any way to stop this from happening?

```
<!-- Replaces the document with the text "from onclick." -->
<button onclick="write('from onclick.')">Write Function</button>

<!-- Logs the text "Alternate write function triggered... from onclick." -->
<button onclick="altWrite('from onclick.')">Alternate Write Function</button>

<script>
  function write (arg) {
    console.log("Write function triggered... " + arg);
  }

  function altWrite (arg) {
    console.log("Alternate write function triggered... " + arg);
  }

  // Logs the text "Write function triggered... from code."
  write("from code.");

  // Logs the text "Alternate write function triggered... from code."
  altWrite("from code.");
</script>
```

Comment: `onclick="window.write('from onclick.')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline handlers unfortunately have unintuitive `with` blocks for:

(1) the element that they're called on (here, the button)

(2) the document:

[image]

So, when `write` is called from the inline handler, the scope chain *first* sees the `write` property on `document` (and calls it as a result), instead of continuing on to search for the `write` property on `window` (which is where the write function you defined exists).

The solution is to not use an inline handler: use `addEventListener` instead.

```js
function write(arg) {
  console.log("Write function triggered... " + arg);
}

function altWrite(arg) {
  console.log("Alternate write function triggered... " + arg);
}
const [button1, button2] = document.querySelectorAll('button');
button1.addEventListener('click', write);
button2.addEventListener('click', altWrite);
```

```html
<button>Write Function</button>
<button>Alternate Write Function</button>
```